# pip not found after installation

Tags: python, installation, pip, pycharm

I installed 'pip' on python, after it tells me that I don't have pip:[image]

Here it tells me that the installation was ok:

[image]

But then I'm trying to install this:

[image]

but it tells me:

[image]

Why 'pip' not found?

EDIT: a picture for Lewis's answer :

[image]

Screenshot number 5:
[image]

Comment: are you using python 2.6 on purpose? using a very old version of python may be the issue.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen If I write on console `python -V` it gives me `3.6.0`

Comment: your 4th screenshot has a proposed solution to to use the system terminal and says your python interpreter is `2.6` then the easy install says it used `2.7`.  If `python` on "console" (terminal?) refers to the correct version then does `python -m pip -V` work?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I added another screenshot tried `python -m pip -V`

Comment: the output of `python -m pip`  would indicate that it's installed and usable. so where something would tell you to use the command `pip` instead just use `python -m pip`

Comment: PyCharm's trying to install using `pip` on Python 2.6. Which version of Python do you want to use: 3.6? If so, check your PyCharm interpreter settings to make sure it's set to 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `easy_install` installed try running: `sudo easy_install pip` in your terminal and restarting PyCharm.

I see you are using an old version of Python (or at least have it installed). Try running `pip3 install name_of_package` if you are looking to install through python 3.

Comment: I tried this now, I can't add a pic to here, so I will add it to my post.

Comment: @Nehorai if this answer fixed your issue you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: plus one for effort

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the script is being run from the wrong place. Try to run it from the regular terminal. Remember to get higher privilege,or pip may fail.

Comment: can you add more detiales please?

Comment: plus one for effort

Comment: Well,sometimes the program is not allowed to install things. Running `sudo pip install TorCtl` on the terminal will get rid of it. There may be a problem with the version of Python. 2.6 is kinda old. Try to upgrade it to 2.7 and try again.